# How to pass value from included component's state back to parent component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a problem to find a way to easy get state value from component in other component. When I click on any tag.

I want to append value of tag to list state in Form component if tag is clicked. Is there any simply way to do this ?

I have component like this:

```
var Tag = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      checked: false
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setState({
      checked: false
    });
  },
  _onChange: function(event) {
     if(this.state.checked == false){
       this.setState({
         checked: true
       });
     } else {
       this.setState({
         checked: false
       });
     }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="review-tag">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id={this.props.id}
          name={this.props.name}
          checked={this.state.checked}
          value={this.props.id}/>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.name} onClick={this._onChange}>{this.props.name}</label>
      </div>
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.props.name}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var allTags = tags;

var ReviewTag = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    const tagComps = allTags.map(function(tag){
      return <Tag {...tag}/>;
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {tagComps}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Tag component have included value at rendering and I have to get value of each tag in my ReviewForm component which looks like this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var ReviewForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      Author: '',
      Tags: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setState({
      Author: author,
      Tags: tags
    });
  },

  submit: function (e){
    var self;

    e.preventDefault();
    self = this;

    var data = {
      tags: this.state.Tags,
      author: this.state.Author
    };

    for (var key in data) {
      fd.append(key, data[key]);
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/reviews/submit/',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log('Review added successfully.');
    })
    .error(function(msg) {
      var errors = msg.responseJSON;
      console.log(errors);
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    <div className="scolumn">
       <ReviewTag/>
    </div>
  }
})
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Why you have two returns in `Tag.render`? Only the first one will ever be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to set state in `componentDidMount` — remove that piece of code.
2. Really, couldn't all of that...

`_onChange: function(event) {
     if(this.state.checked == false){
       this.setState({
         checked: true
       });
     } else {
       this.setState({
         checked: false
       });
     }
  },`

be substituted with `_onChange: function(event) { this.setState(checked: !this.state.cheked) }`?

3. `allTags` should be passed as property, not as outer scope variable.

Now to your main question.

Move state to parent component (`ReviewForm`). You can have state as a hash with `{name: isChecked}` structure (`name` is Tag's name, and `isChecked` is boolean). Pass it down to `ReviewTag` and futher down to `Tag` as property. Also pass down your `_onChange` handler as property (it should be moved to parent component — `ReviewForm` — as well).

So when the Tag is checked, it calls ReviewForm's handler, and ReviewForm's handler changes its own state accordingly.